# What is meaning of "Each possible outcome can be specified in advance" in definition of Statistical Experiment?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, definition

I see the below definition of Statistical Experiment [here](http://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=Statistical_experiment) on resourceful site startrek.com

Statistical Experiment
All statistical experiments have three things in common:

1. The experiment can have more than one possible outcome.
2. Each possible outcome can be specified in advance.
3. The outcome of the experiment depends on chance.

But I'm struggling to digest 
 the point 2 **"Each possible outcome can be specified in advance."**
 when the **outcome** is a **Continuous random variable, which by definition can have infinite values**.

Comment: The outcomes are specified using a rule that includes all the values. For example, "x is greater than 0" or "x is any real number" both specify an infinite number of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially answered in comments:

The outcomes are specified using a rule that includes all the values. For example, "x is greater than 0" or "x is any real number" both specify an infinite number of values. – David Smith